# set variable from component in instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set data variable of Vue instance from component. Is that even possible.

```
Vue.component('graph', {
    template: '',
    props: {},
    data: function () {
    methods: {
        setBtn: function () {
           //here i want to set ShowBtn variable for example to false
        },
    },  this.getUserRecordStatistic();
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
       showBtn: null
    },
    methods: {},
});
```

Comment: Try saving the return value of `new View({...})` and see if you can do it through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Vue.component('graph', {
  template: '',
  props: {},
  data: {},
  methods: {
    setBtn: function () {
      app.showBtn = false;
    },
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showBtn: null
  },
  methods: {},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `data` on the root vue instance through `vm.$root`.

```
setBtn: function () {
   this.$root.showBtn = false;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice you should avoid directly setting params on other components. Vue is intended to decouple its components therefore directly editing a param, although possible, runs in the face of this. Check out the components guide for more info, specifically: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Therefore rather than directly editing this param you should emit an event from the component which you can listen for on the root - or any other component that sets the `graph` component, i.e.

**graph component** emit an event

```
Vue.component('graph', {
  methods: {
    activateBtn () {
      this.$emit('set-button', true)
    },
    ...
```

**root** or any component that sets `graph` in its template

```
# template
<graph @set-button="setBtn"></graph>

# script
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showBtn: false
  },
  methods: {
    setBtn (state) {
      this.showBtn = state
    },
  },
})
```